# Tensorflow in Pyinstaller on MacOS. Saving model fails with TensorShapeProto error

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, conda, pyinstaller

I have a simple test script that just saves and loads a tensorflow model.

I passes when run from python on my system.  But fails to load the model when I run it from a pyinstaller package, it fails with `TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected tensorflow.TensorShapeProto got tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.`

The full script is

```
import tempfile
from dataclasses import dataclass
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf


@dataclass
class ColorFilterModel(tf.Module):
    rgb_filter_strengths = (0., 1., 1.)
    def compute_mahalonabis_sq_heatmap(self, image):
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * tf.constant(self.rgb_filter_strengths), axis=-1)

def test_basic_save_and_load_model():
    print("Testing basic model save/load")
    model = ColorFilterModel()
    numpy_image = cv2.imread(tf.keras.utils.get_file('basalt_canyon.jpg', "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petered/data/master/images/basalt_canyon.jpg"))
    print(f"Image shape: {numpy_image.shape}")
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
        concrete_func = tf.function(model.compute_mahalonabis_sq_heatmap, input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8)]).get_concrete_function()
        result_original = concrete_func(numpy_image)
        print(f"Result shape: {result_original.shape}")
        tf.saved_model.save(model, tmpdirname, signatures={'mahal': concrete_func})  # THIS LINE FAILS
        loaded_func = tf.saved_model.load(tmpdirname).signatures['mahal']
        result_loaded = loaded_func(image=numpy_image)['output_0']
        assert tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(result_original, result_loaded))
    print("Passed test_basic_save_and_load_model")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_basic_save_and_load_model()
```

When run from pyinstaller, it first gets the error message

```
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph is not available in this environment: functions lack code information. This is typical of some environments like the interactive Python shell. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#access-to-source-code for more information.
```

Then outputs:

```
Testing basic model save/load
Image shape: (1500, 2000, 3)
2023-05-24 17:20:13.912138: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
Result shape: (1500, 2000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    test_basic_save_and_load_model()
  File "video_scanner/detection_utils/test_standalone_model_io.py", line 22, in test_basic_save_and_load_model
    tf.saved_model.save(model, tmpdirname, signatures={'mahal': concrete_func})
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1232, in save
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1268, in save_and_return_nodes
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1441, in _build_meta_graph
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1396, in _build_meta_graph_impl
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 794, in _fill_meta_graph_def
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 607, in _generate_signatures
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 474, in _tensor_dict_to_tensorinfo
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 475, in <dictcomp>
  File "tensorflow/python/saved_model/utils_impl.py", line 78, in build_tensor_info_internal
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected tensorflow.TensorShapeProto got tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.
[11509] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected tensorflow.TensorShapeProto got tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.
```

Oddly this does not seem to happen on Windows - only Mac.

If I do the saving outside of Pyinstaller and only do the loading from pyinstaller, I get an error on load `AttributeError: as_proto`, which I'm guessing has the same route-cause.

What is going on, and how can I save/load tensorflow models in a pyinstaller app?

Answer (score 0):

My tensorflow had been installed with

```
 conda install -c apple tensorflow
```

When I started a new env and installed with

```
 pip install tensorflow
```

The problem went away.

So it looks like `conda install -c apple tensorflow` does not play well with `tf.saved_model.save/tf.saved_model.load` when the program has been built with pyinstaller.